# How can I get button pressed time when I holding button on

Tags: android, button, time

I have a button, I press it and continue to holding it, if holding time exceeds certain time interval it fires some kind of intent, how can i do this.
Thanks

Comment: what have you done till mow post that

Comment: You should try out with Longclick listener.

Comment: I tried it (LongClickListener), but the time duration is not enough long.

Comment: anything like show Toast if holding time as long as 5 seconds with holding it.

Comment: you can try my answer

Comment: Did you find a solution? I may need to do the same thing also. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

try this

You can use `Touch Listener` to do this.

Try:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handler.postDelayed(run, 5000/* OR the amount of time you want */);
                break;

            default:
                handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Where `b` is the `view` (in your case it should button) on which you want to make long click.

And `Runnable` `run` is as follows

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code to run on long click

    }
};
```

Hope it will help... :)

Comment: How to invoke an event every 5000(amount of time which is required)?

Answer (score 7):

Detect `[ACTION_DOWN][1]` and `[ACTION_UP][2]` events.

When button is pressed (`[ACTION_DOWN][1]`), start timer, measure time... If timer exceeds, invoke Intent. When button is released (`[ACTION_UP][2]`) stop timer.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch ( arg1.getAction() ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //start timer
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // invoke intent
                }
            }, 5000); //time out 5s
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //stop timer
            timer.cancel();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

When button will be pressed, timer will be started. If button will be released before 5 seconds timeout, nothing will happen, otherwise your desired action will be executed.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking. He needs to launch the action if a certain interval has passed while the button is still held down.

Comment: Where is problem? If timer will reach timeout this means button is still down because timer wasn't stopped in ACTION_UP.

Comment: you're right. Can you please clarify this in your comments as well? That's how I ended up misunderstanding.

Comment: I updated also example, so i hope it is more clear what i thought.

Answer (score 5):

```
long lastDown;
long keyPressedDuration ;

button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           keyPressedDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
        }
     }
  };
```

Comment: I don't think that this does what the OP asked i.e. start an action if ACTION_DOWN (because of a hold-down) has been going on for a duration other than the long-press duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onTouchEvent and calculate the offset between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`;

Code below will run a runnable after x amount of time and also remove it if `ACTION_UP` is called before x time. Also included how you can get an exact time value...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // record the start time
        mStartTime = ev.getEventTime();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTaskToRun, MAXIMUM_LONG_PRESS_INTERVAL);
    } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // record the end time
        mEndTime = ev.getEventTime();

        long keyPressedDuration = mEndTime - mStartTime;

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTaskToRun);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Are you calculating the keyPressedDuration for checking if some interval has been exceeded by the time ACTION_UP occurs? It's not doing anything in your code now...

Also, MAXIMUM_LONG_PRESS_INTERVAL is something we define, isn't it?

Comment: Calling post delayed postDelayed() with some interval doesn't do anything? The calculations of there for reference only. the Handler is doing all the work.

Comment: I was saying that keyPressedDuration isn't doing anything; it's defined and a value is computed, but it isn't used elsewhere. I do understand that the handler does the work. As for the calculations only being a reference, that is fine. The intervals can be user defined. That's what I hoped you meant.

Comment: Ah! I missed another thing. You said, "and also remove it if ACTION_UP is called before x time," but the code removes the event on ACTION_UP regardless of time elapsed. This behaviour is what the OP wants, afaik. However, the behaviour you describe needs an additional check on the keyPressedDuration, right?

Comment: no, "if holding time exceeds certain time interval it fires some kind of intent" If MAXIMUM_LONG_PRESS_INTERVAL expires before ACTION_UP is called the event is fired.. eg the button has been held passed the "certain time amount interval". Otherwise we don't care, remove the delayed task as it has not met the minimum interval.

Comment: you've missed meaning. I'm clear on what the OP wants and I'm also sure your code example does what the OP wants. What I'm talking about is your description which seems to point at calling the handler on ACTION_UP if the time has elapsed in addition to everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I got an Exception when I used a Timer!
You can also use a Handler like below -

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable run = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do your Stuff!     
        }
    };
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motion) {
                switch (motion.getAction() ) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        handler.postDelayed(run, 5000); //5 seconds delay
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                        return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }});
```

Answer (score -2):

*Edit.*

Apparently, I have misunderstood the question. Please see @Hardik and @Lunar solutions above.

---

You could get away with doing something like this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        long duration = 0L;

        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                duration = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                duration = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - duration;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (duration > YOUR_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS) {
            // Do stuff...
        }

        return true; // or whatever you want to return.
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for copy past but your code will not worked.

Comment: My answer is more of a solution showcase and as such, not tested and definitely not designed to be a copy-paste solution. Your downvote is a joke.

Comment: please write if logic code inside of switch case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: curtisLoew, your code doesn't answer the question since it only does something after an ACTION_UP occurs and a certain amount of time has passed. @Hardik, and Lunar have posted solutions. You might want to look at those and present an alternative approach or something.

Comment: @batbrat you are right, I misunderstood the question.