# How to give visual feedback to the user while he is pressing down a button in Android?

Tags: android

in my app I need a button to be pressed down during 2 seconds, and after that to trigger an action. Thanks to this question ([How can I get button pressed time when I holding button on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606977/how-can-i-get-button-pressed-time-when-i-holding-button-on)) I have it working, but I need the user can see that he/she actually is pressing down the button, for example with a 'loading icon' or something that indicate the user to continue pressing down the button. And if he stops pressing down the button, I want that 'loading icon' to go away.

This is my code:

```
handler = new Handler();
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                Toast.makeText(Visor.this, "Hold the button for 2 sec...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                handler.postDelayed(run, 2000);
            } else {

                handler.removeCallbacks(run);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

(`run` is the action it triggers after 2 seconds)

My question is: is there any callback method that indicates if the user is pressing down the button? I have tried with `event.isButtonPressed(int Button)`, but it works only on API 21, and my app is for < 10.

Thank you.

Update: As @Divers and @Blackbelt have pointed out, `setOnTouchListener` combined with `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is all what I need to solve this problem.

Comment: `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is a good hint,

Comment: onTouch is already callback which you are looking for.

Comment: The amount of people allergic to googling is too damn high ...

Comment: Thanks A LOT guys. I didn't realize that that method is the callback I was looking for. And @2Dee , I have googled, but as you can see I'm a beginner in Android, and in programming in general.