# How to increment progress bar while pressing a button?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I am wanting to show a progress bar while holding down a button. Once the progress bar is completed, I want invoke a function. My problem is incrementing the progress bar while the button is being held down. My approach is to get the amount of time the button is pressed in seconds. Then use that time to correlate the progress. When the progress bar is complete, I will invoke another function. Right now the `onLongClickListener` is only being called once. I thought this would continually be called while the button was pressed.

```
        btn.setOnLongClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Long click detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var seconds =  System.currentTimeMillis()
            Log.d(TAG, "seconds: $seconds")
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a custom progress bar which extends from ProgressBar as below:

```
public MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
{
   @Override
   public void setProgress(int progress)
   {
       super.setProgress(progress);
       if(progress == this.getMax())
       {
           //invoke a function here
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes but right now I need to find a way to get the duration of button pressed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606977/how-can-i-get-button-pressed-time-when-i-holding-button-on would be correct answer for your question