# How to wait for n miliseconds in onTouch()?

Tags: android, handler, runnable, touch-event

In **onTouch()** method I'm listening for ***MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE*** event, which is firing while the finger is hovering over the certain button on the screen (i.e. user is holding his finger on that button). The button has listener attached to it, so **onTouch()** method is triggered when the finger is swiping above that button (and **ACTION_MOVE** actually happens dozens of time/second). This behaviour is exaclty what I need.

EDIT:
The only event I am insterested in is **ACTION_MOVE**, i.e. I need to execute code only when finger is hovering that button (only if ACTION_MOVE is happening inside the time window of 5000ms). I don't have **ACTION_DOWN** nor **ACTION_UP** event.

The key thing here to notice is that this event is happening hundred times in only a couple of seconds, when the finger is "moving" above that specific button.

What I am trying to do is wait for certain period of time (e.g. 5000ms), and when 5000ms has passed (and user is **still** holding his finger on that button!), I want to call one specific method to do some task. If user is touching and holding different button, the method shouldn't be called.

I have tried using Handler and Runnable, but the problem is **onTouch()** method, which is calling this Handler hundred of times in just a couple of seconds:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // call specific method to do some task here
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

I have also tried calling:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

and

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

when the finger is not hovering over button to cancel the Handler, but it is not working correctly.
Can someone give me the idea what should I do to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Check this, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607081/7120614

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to mention that I need to execute code only when finger is hovering that button (i.e. only if ACTION_MOVE is happening inside the time window of 5000ms). I will add this info to the question.

Comment: I think, you should also ask detouch events (forgot how to do it). Because the user can touch the button, then release and after 4 seconds press again and touch for 2 seconds. In this case it shouldn't be called.

Comment: Maybe you should add two variables: one for touch counter, second for time (when the user touched the button).